# How can I use Radix Sort for an array of float numbers?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, data-structures, radix-sort

How can I sort some float data in an array , using Radix Sort? 
I think that I should multiply all data into the smallest power of 10 which makes them integer. But I don't know how I can understand that suitable power.
This is the c++ code for sorting an array of integers.
Can anybody help me doing this?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
//Get maximum value in arr[]

    int findMax(int arr[], int n)
{
    int max = arr[0];
     for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
      if (arr[i] > max)
        max = arr[i];
    return max;
}

// A function to do counting sort of arr[] according to
// the digit represented by exp.

    void countSort(int arr[], int n, int exp)
{
    int outputArr[n]; // output array
    int i, count[10] = {0};

// Store count of occurrences in count[]

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      count[ (arr[i]/exp)%10 ]++;

// Change count[i] so that count[i] now contains actual
//  position of this digit in output[]

    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
      count[i] += count[i - 1];

// Build the output array

    for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   {
      outputArr[count[ (arr[i]/exp)%10 ] - 1] = arr[i];
      count[ (arr[i]/exp)%10 ]--;
   }

// Copy the output array to arr[], so that arr[] now
// contains sorted numbers according to current digit

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      arr[i] = outputArr[i];
}

// The main function to that sorts arr[] of size n using Radix Sort

    void radixsort(int arr[], int n)
    {

      int max = findMax(arr, n);

// Do counting sort for every digit. Note that instead
// of passing digit number, exp is passed. exp is 10^i
// where i is current digit number

  for (int exp = 1; max/exp > 0; exp *= 10)
    countSort(arr, n, exp);
    }

// A utility function to print an array

    void print(int arr[], int n)
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }

   int main()
 {
    int arr[] = {506,2,41,33,5,965,73};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    radixsort(arr, n);
    print(arr, n);
    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Except for special numbers like NAN, you can treat floats as 32 bit sign + magnitude numbers for sorting purposes. For radix sorting, it would be simplest to convert sign + magnitude numbers to 32 bit unsigned integers, then convert back after the sort. Example macros to convert from float to unsigned and from unsigned to float. Note that -0 would be treated as less than +0, a potential stability issue, but floating point operations normally do not produce a -0, and this can be dealt with by checking for -0 and treating it the same as +0 in the code. Cast a float to an unsigned int before using these macros.

```
#define FLOAT_2_U(x) ((x)^(((~(x) >> 31)-1) | 0x80000000))
#define U_2_FLOAT(x) ((x)^((( (x) >> 31)-1) | 0x80000000))
```

Comment: Does this work universally, or just for IEEE floats? Also, what happens with NAN and other special values? Finally, does this handle denormalized numbers correctly?

Comment: @JimMischel - This method is meant for IEEE floats, specifically floats that are the equivalent of sign and magnitude. Denormalized numbers should work ok. Special values will be sorted to the front or back depending on the exponent value.